# Bash Eval Syntax Error Every time I open terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, path

Every time I open terminal, my mac makes a multitude of error sounds, and returns this output:

```
-bash: eval: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `?
-bash: eval: line 4: `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:????:H9???:?::I?F:A??I???E?closf?E?e::I?|\$???:܅:?E?proxf?E?y:?{8??:?{8??:h:=:?E?preff?E?s:H? H??tH?:I?H?]?H??:uAHF\$?:??:!?:1?L???\$7:H??H?QH?BH?FH
```

Around 40 other errors appear below this in terminal as well. Terminal functions normally after that, but it is getting quite annoying. Any idea what's going on? Hard to know what file is having this issue. Checked the .bashrc files, but came up dry. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Comment: The startup file is ~/.bash_profile , if that does not exist then ~/.profile   ~/.bashrc is only read if explicitly called - unless you have altered Terminal app defaults

Comment: It could also be `~/.bash_login`, although that's rare compared to `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

Your PATH line is bad. It's got a `` ` `` at the beginning of the line as the error shows, plus some bad content at the end.

This is probably in your `~/.bash_profile` which is sourced by default. Check the content of this file.

You can make bash print before executing a line using `-x`, i.e. `bash -x`. This can help narrow down where the issue is occurring by showing the lines of script before they are executed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `~/.bash_profile` was corrupted starting at line 4 during a dotnet automatic upgrade.

Before trying to recover it from your backups, I advise you to type :

```
ls -l ~/.bash_profile
```

to get the date of last modification of your bash profile so as to validate my hypothesis about the origin of this accident.

Next, recover your `~/.bash_profile` from your Time Machine backup before this accident.